# How to know at render time what partials are being used in a Razor page in ASPNET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware, razor-pages, partial-views

I have an ASPNET Core (.net6) project with a main page layout that automatically includes styles and scripts in the page bases on the page file name. Example: if you have a page called me/details (the file being me/details.cshtml) and there is a file called wwwroot/me/details.css, a reference to it will be included by my layout page inthe head of the html. The same happens for script files, but at the end of the body

I wanted to do the same for partials views. I want to include specific styles and script file references in the html for any partial views being rendered in the page, without extra code in the partials. Is there any way to know at render time, or at least at the middleware level, what partial views are being used in a page?

Comment: Do you want to dynamic add the partial view and its CSS style and script file? Without add the Style file and Script file in the partial view, you have to add them in the main layout page one by one. But, for the CSS style, I suggest you could consider using [CSS Isolation In Razor Pages](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/355/css-isolation-in-razor-pages), then, when add the partial view, it will auto add the CSS style, but for the Script file, you have to add them in the Layout page.

Comment: I don't want to have code in the partials that add styles and scripts to the page. I want to do it "on demand", in the page layout.

I already have that in my page layout for the style and script of the page itself, but I couldn't figure it out, from the main layout, how to discover what partials are being used.

I'm not a fan of how some of the default script and style bundling work, and I also don't like what CSS isolation does.

It is not a case of isolation that I'm looking for. I don't want the unnecessary styles and scripts to be download if not required.